# How to actually copy a file to a USB, instead of whatever it is happens now

Tags: linux, files, windows, usb

I tried finding the answer online,

but the search results don't match my query anymore

**How does anyone copy a file to a USB with normal expected**

**behavior like it was for decades, when after the process**

**was complete, you could immediately remove your USB drive**

**without waiting for secret backroom deals between your**

**operating system and your USB drive, and your files...**

Comment: after reading your comments to one of the answers below, I think that you have an XY question ... you are trying to solve an apparent problem with USB flash drive write speed by replacing the OS, and your question is about the OS instead of being about the slow write speed

Answer (score 3):

Your question concerns the synchronization status of your USB supported filesystem.

The I/O primitives (`open, read, write, close`) do not ensure synchronization.

The `sync` command will ensure, as well as `unmount` of course.

So, the typical process is:

```
cp /path/file1 /myusb/
sync -f /myusb
```

After that, your data will be synchronized.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the wrong answer due to the reality that it doesn't solve the problem whatsoever, and just goes through the same faulty process that is a problem to begin with.

Comment: If you notice that the behaviour has changed over time, it could be related to the kernel buffer cache size. The bigger it is, the later the kernel is forced to sync. I suppose this is tuneable, not sure for best results.

Comment: @New_Guest The fault is not in the OS but in your understanding. By default, Linux buffers writes for performance, it always has and always will (note that there are mount options, like `sync`, that cause all writes to be done synchronously. And programs can use the O_SYNC flag when opening a file for write) . You can tell Linux to flush unwritten buffers to disk with the `sync` command. sync is also run automatically when you `umount` a drive.  You should **always** unmount a drive (any drive, not just USB) before you remove it, otherwise you risk corruption of the files or filesystem.

Comment: There is no deception going on.  This is, and always has been, well-documented behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is funny: **so you publicly admit you always actually yanked out USB device out of the machine without ensuring proper data integrity for decades?**

Even in '98 when USB for Windows 98 was first introduced in Windows 98 SE, I remember the only safe way to remove USB mass storage device, was to execute "device eject" command from "systray", or in "my computer".

Are you trying to tell us, that instead of doing that, you always yanked the key out right after copying, when **you decided** data was written? I don't even want to know how much data you silently lost or mangled over all those decades, because of that. Your ignorance is mind boggling.

As was explained above `sync` is good idea to ensure data of the file got there,  but `umount` is only surefire, as it ensures FS on the device is actually properly frozen and ready for device extraction.

`sync` does not ensure eviction of everything that can be evicted only  `umount` does, like major filesystem structures.

Given your propensity for shortcuts, I suggest you to learn `umount` is only proper way for you. Thak us later.

PS.:
Just a friendly hint, both `umount` or `sync`, especially on FAT(32) formatted drives can take even minutes for huge files (~2GB, ~4GB on FAT32) on huge drives, so don't panic - it's the result of conflict between nature of FAT system and nature of Linux.